# i don't know why , when i'm install matplotlib it's can't

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lfu2ezm2\\matplotlib_a6f263fb06cb49b0ba9dd9f1bc0eef1f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lfu2ezm2\\matplotlib_a6f263fb06cb49b0ba9dd9f1bc0eef1f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-iz0t3g38\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\USer\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Include\matplotlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/69780663/4046632

Answer (score 0):

There is no version for matplotlib in Python 3.10, try using an older version of python.